# Sum of 2 or more random numbers

Tags: javascript, random, sum

```js
var sum = ? // sum of two or more random numbers;

function example() {
var random= Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 2;
}
```

1. Function example was maded more than 2 times
2. In var sum should be the value of all the random numbers that was maded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want sum to be the sum of the numbers generated in example? No matter how many times example is called.. but you will call it at least twice..

Initialize sum to 0, and add the random number every time you call example..

If you want to know how many random numbers were sued you can add another var, count, init it as 0 as well, and increment it every time example is called..

```
var sum = 0; // sum of all random numbers created in example

function example() {
    sum += Math.floor(Math.random() * 11) + 2;
}
```